# vim autocmd BufNewfile executed multiple times

Tags: vim, autocmd

My ~/.vimrc contains only

```
so ~/config/vim/vimrc
```

~/config/vim/vimrc contains usual options, few mappings and source files for different filetype, I've got :

```
autocmd FileType cpp so ~/config/vim/filetype/cpp.vimrc
```

And in that file, I have defined the following function, which I want to call every time I open a new cpp header in order to avoid double inclusion :

```
python import vim

function! s:insert_gates()
python << endPython
hpp = vim.current.buffer.name
hpp = hpp[hpp.rfind('/') + 1:]
hpp = hpp.upper()
hpp = hpp.replace('.', '_')
vim.current.buffer.append("#ifndef " + hpp)
vim.current.buffer.append("# define " + hpp)
vim.current.buffer.append("")
vim.current.buffer.append("#endif")
endPython
endfunction

autocmd BufNewFile *.hpp call <SID>insert_gates()
```

And then, if I ask my shell for:

```
vim -O3 t1.hpp t2.hpp t3.hpp
```

I got:

```
|                     |#ifndef T2_HPP       |#ifndef T3_HPP       |
|                     |# define T2_HPP      |# define T3_HPP      |
|                     |                     |                     |
|                     |#endif               |#endif               |
|                     |                     |#ifndef T3_HPP       |
|                     |                     |# define T3_HPP      |
|                     |                     |                     |
|                     |                     |#endif               |
|                     |                     |                     |
|_____________________|_____________________|_____________________|
|t1.h                 |t2.h                 |t3.h                 |
```

That's not exactly what I want... Do you see my mistake ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referenced [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html), Vim creates a *new* `autocmd` each time you open a new file. To prevent this, replace that section of your `.vimrc` with:

```
python import vim

function! s:insert_gates()
python << endPython
hpp = vim.current.buffer.name
hpp = hpp[hpp.rfind('/') + 1:]
hpp = hpp.upper()
hpp = hpp.replace('.', '_')
vim.current.buffer.append("#ifndef " + hpp)
vim.current.buffer.append("# define " + hpp)
vim.current.buffer.append("")
vim.current.buffer.append("#endif")
endPython
endfunction

augroup insertgates
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile *.hpp call <SID>insert_gates()
augroup END
```

Comment: What does `<SID>` mean?